# Not able to read data from Firebase Database in Android Studio

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsoup

I have an application that is getting price,title etc. data from website. I get data with using jsoup with html parsing. I use a different class for html parsing. I also added membership system from Firebase Authentication to my application. Each user have different product lists. Products are located with user id in database. I want app to get values from database table but it gets titles of tables. My problem is getting titles from database table.

You can see the problem at [this photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/559yw.png)

You can see another class at [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJZtw.png)

How can i get values ?

```
package com.example.lkuygulama;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UrunEklemeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
        DatabaseReference reference;
        private String userId;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthlistener;
        public ArrayList<String> goster = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView view;
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
        public Button aramam,bildirim,liste;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_urun_ekleme);

        Urun urun = new Urun();

        bildirim=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bildirimButon);
        liste = (Button) findViewById(R.id.urunListeButon);
        view=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listele);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,goster);

    view.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        mAuthlistener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                userId = user.getUid();
            }
        };


        tanimla();
        listele();

            bildirim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view) {
                        gonderBildirim();
                   }
               });
    }

    private void tanimla() {
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    }

    private void listele() {

        reference.child("urunler").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


                    String valeu =dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    goster.add(valeu);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });
    }


    private void gonderBildirim() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BildirimActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void gonderAra() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AramaActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void gonderListe() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of code and the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual code and JSON as text, the latter of which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes them searchable, allows us to easily use them to test with your actual data and use them in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: okey now i m doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use getValue(String.class). 
Like this :

```
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String valeu =dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            goster.add(valeu);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

I recommend **addListenerForSingleValueEvent** instead of **addChildEventListener**.

Comment: can you contact me via whatsapp? and I'm getting such an error

Comment: Yes we can contact via watsapp.